# Tichel wearer moves to Sheitel covered community

Tags: halacha, minhag, women, tzibur-community, hair-covering

If a woman who is custom to covering by means of Tichel/Mitpachat moves to a community in which it is custom for women to wear Sheitels, should she switch to Sheitels? If she attends a synagogue in which she is the only one covered with Tichel, is she obligated to follow the minhag of the synagogue?

Comment: What if everyone wears blue shoes but she likes brown shoes?

Comment: It depends on if she's Sephardic and whether or not she cares what Ovadia Yosef has to say

Comment: rth116, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks your first question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: I suspect that the ideal behavior would depend a great deal on the particular community and the particular woman. Her best bet would probably be to consult her rabbi.

Comment: I think you will find different answers based on what is preceived to be the most ideal way of covering ones hair. On the other hand if you are coming from the point of view that both are equally valid and there is not an advantage to either one then you could make the argument being more like the majority in the community makes more sense

Comment: One should never be different to the tsibbur.  I would say she should rather not go to shul than be different. @Dude. A woman anyway doesnt have to  go to shul.

Comment: @newcomer source? And don't tell me Al tifrosh min hatzibur. Tifrosh doesn't mean different

Comment: From delving through a few articles on this subject, there seem to be about equal pros and cons for a woman wearing a sheitel in the first place. One argument is that many sheitels look much like real hair, which, according to the claim, defeats the idea of covering one's own hair. I would lean to following your own minhag of using the tichel vs. the community's practice (BTW, a snood may be a good "middle" option, in this case.) As for shul attendance, it depends how uncomfortable you feel standing out, and getting comments from, perhaps, some *yachnes*.

Comment: lo tisgodedu includes everything @user613.  And al tifrosh does mean being different. One shouldnt be happy when everyone is sad. etc.

Comment: לא יהא אדם ער בין הישנים
ולא ישן בין הערים.
ולא בוכה בין השוחקים
ולא שוחק בין הבוכים.
ולא יושב בין העומדים
ולא עומד בין היושבים.
ולא קורא בין השונים
ולא שונה בין הקוראים.
כללו של דבר אל ישנה אדם ממנהג הבריות. 
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/makor/zuta/5-2.htm

Comment: @newcomer Al tifrosh means don't separate yourself, if everyone is mourning for something, or is in danger etc join them and don't separate yourself. It doesn't mean not to dress differently or to have different minhogim

Comment: כללו של דבר אל ישנה אדם ממנהג הבריות @user613